# Differences in the boot_command between Ubuntu Server 21.10 and 20.04

Tags: boot, 21.10

Is there anyway to troubleshoot the boot_command between the various versions of Ubuntu servers?  I spend hours searching google and finding vast differences in way people write the boot command.

I am using packer to create VM's for virtualbox. My current boot command looks like

```
"<enter><enter><f6><esc><wait> ", "autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/", "<wait><enter>"
```

This command works on Ubuntu Server 20.04 but fails on version 21.10.

My problem is that there seems to be no consensus on how the boot command should be written:

Another website has:

```
  "boot_command": [
    "<esc><wait><esc><wait><f6><wait><esc><wait>",
    "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
    "autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/ ",
    "--- <enter>"
```

Another one I saw had several rows of `"<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>"`.

I am still searching documents and the internet to find a process of determining what a valid boot_command is.

Does anyone have a boot_command that works with 21.10? If so how did anyone figure out what it should be.

I am relatively new to Ubuntu and I have not used autoinstall in the past and the differences between the old preseed.cfg way and subuquity for servers and the desktop ubuquity are very confusing until I figure out the logic behind it all.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Using packer's new HCL2 templates for creating boxes the following boot command works with Ubuntu Server 21.10. For json you can use the older style "boot_command": [] syntax.

```
boot_command = [
            " <wait>",
            " <wait>",
            " <wait>",
            " <wait>",
            " <wait>",
            "c",
            "<wait>",
            "set gfxpayload=keep",
            "<enter><wait>",
            "linux /casper/vmlinuz quiet<wait>",
            " autoinstall<wait>",
            " ds=nocloud-net<wait>",
            "\\;s=http://<wait>",
            "{{.HTTPIP}}<wait>",
            ":{{.HTTPPort}}/<wait>",
            " ---",
            "<enter><wait>",
            "initrd /casper/initrd<wait>",
            "<enter><wait>",
            "boot<enter><wait>"
        ]
```

Comment: This may work but it does not address the question as it is asked.